# Using RxJS 6.x WebSocketSubject client

Tags: websocket, rxjs

I cannot figure out how to use WebSocketSubjects in rxjs `v6.x`

Here's the working HTML/JS for `v5.5.6`. The commented out code is my attempt at getting it working in `v6.x`:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <!-- <script src="https://unpkg.com/@reactivex/rxjs@6.0.0/dist/global/rxjs.umd.js"></script> -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@reactivex/rxjs@5.5.6/dist/global/Rx.js"></script>
    <script>
        // const { WebSocketSubject } = rxjs.webSocket;
        // const socket$ = WebSocketSubject.create('ws://localhost:8080');
        const socket$ = Rx.Observable.webSocket('ws://localhost:8080');
        socket$.subscribe(
                (data) => console.log(data),
                (err) => console.error(err),
                () => console.warn('Completed!')
            );
        socket$.next(JSON.stringify({
            event: 'events',
            data: 'test',
        }));
        console.log('here')
    </script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: So, what's the point of the websocket function then. I still think that version should work and there's a big somewhere. https://medium.com/@keyntaki/how-to-fix-a-broken-websocketsubject-in-rxjs-6-x-566282b90936 says the opposite, that the constructor is broken and the `webSocket` fn works... https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/3874 agrees with you

Comment: Especially since the implementation seems to be `export function webSocket<T>(urlConfigOrSource: string | WebSocketSubjectConfig<T>): WebSocketSubject<T> {
  return new WebSocketSubject<T>(urlConfigOrSource);
}`

Comment: @JamiePate you can read the documentation on the webSocket function [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/observable/dom/webSocket.ts), it is basically a wrapper around the w3c-compatible WebSocket object provided by the browser. Not sure why the webSocket function isn't working for you. In the most recent version of rxjs it just returns a `new WebSocketSubject` (as you can see in my link).

Comment: I think it may have been due to the Ng serve proxy, and I switched to `rxjs-websockets` anyways because my use case isn't symmetrical (outgoing data types are not the same as incoming, which seems like it would be more common anyways and causes problems when you use WebSocketSubject<T> because then T must be a union type). My comment refers to the code samples where he says he was using the syntax wrong but the only difference appears to be `webSocket()` vs `new WebSocketSubject()` but maybe he was using the commented `WebSocketSubject.create()` instead? Hard to tell with edited questions :(

Comment: ER, 'you' I guess, not 'he'

Comment: yes, you are right, the only difference I found here between 5.5.6 and 6.0.0 was using `new WebSocketSubject()` in 6 where we used to use `Rx.Observable.webSocket()` in 5.5.6... I will edit the question again to try to make it more clear.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I got it working with `rxjs@6.1.0`. As I suspected, I was just using the version 6 syntax wrong. See working example:

```html
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@reactivex/rxjs@6.1.0/dist/global/rxjs.umd.js"></script>
    <script>
        const { WebSocketSubject } = rxjs.webSocket;
        const socket$ = new WebSocketSubject('ws://localhost:8080');
        socket$.subscribe(
            (data) => console.log(data),
            (err) => console.error(err),
            () => console.warn('Completed!')
        );
        socket$.next({
            event: 'events',
            data: 'test',
        });
        console.log('here')
    </script>
</head>

<body></body>

</html>
```

Comment: This really saved by bacon. In the docs it says all over the place to serialize the object sent to next using `JSON.stringify` [in the docs](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/observable/dom/webSocket.ts#L31-L32) and [here](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-webSocket) That didn't seem to work as well as this solution. Seems like the `webSocket` factory function is broken or something, too, but maybe I had the wrong keys in the object. That also seemed important to have event, and data.