# rxJava2 to rxJs | Question - Will I be able to subscribe to the Server-Side Observable from a Client-Side JavaScript libraries like Angular?

Tags: rxjs, observable, rx-java2, subscribe

Sorry this might be a lame/Rookie question.

Question - Will I be able to subscribe to the Server-Side Observable from a Client-Side JavaScript libraries like Angular?

I'm using RxJava2 on the server-side and RxJs on the client side. I'm curious if this is even possible.

Comment: Observables are essentially functions only executable within the context in which they are defined, so you can't directly subscribe in one context (client side) to an Observable in another context (server side).  However, the stream of data underlying an Observable often needs to be shared - a good way of doing this sharing of data between the backend and the frontend is with a [WebSocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API), rxjs has good support for them with a [WebSocketSubject](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50400143/4233452)

Comment: Answer accepted! I am going with Server Sent Events. looks promising with HTTP/2