# Converting websocket events to observables

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, rxjs, observable

I'm using the [ws library](https://github.com/websockets/ws) to create a websocket client to communicate with a (JSON based) websocket server. Every request must have a unique requestId, and the response will have that same requestId

#### Simplified example of my code

```
let requestId = 0;

const WebSocket = require('ws');
const ws = new WebSocket('ws://www.host.com/path');

ws.on('message', (json) => {
  let obj = JSON.parse(json);

  if (obj.eventType === 'SomeEvent') {
     ws.send({
       requestId,
       command: "DoSomeStuff"
     });
  }
});
```

I would like to implement a send method in my file that internally calls `ws.send()` but returns an observable that resolves when the websocket receives a `ws.on('message')` where the requestId property matches the requestId.

That way I can subscribe to the Observable and change my code to

```
...
  if (obj.eventType === 'SomeEvent') {
     mySendFunction({
       requestId,
       command: "DoSomeStuff"
     }).subscribe(result => {
        // Do something with result here
     }
  }
...
```

Also - sometimes (rarely) the server does not respond to the request. In that case, is there a way to timeout the observable in case a response is not received within a given time period?

---

I've seen implementations that uses an array to map requestId's to promises and then manually resolving them, but I figure that there must be a smarter way to do this directly with RxJS.

Any ideas?

Comment: So you first want to call `send` and then wait for reply via `on`?

Comment: Seems rxjs 5 and 6 have [websocket subject](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44067972/7404943)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A very simple thing you can do is just using `new Observable()`:

```
const mySendFunction = options => new Observable(observer => {
  const handler = ws.on('message', json => {
    let obj = JSON.parse(json);

    if (obj.eventType === options.command) {
      observer.next(obj);
      observer.complete();
    }
  });

  ws.send(options);

  return () => {
    // ...cancel handler?
  };
});
```

Comment: Where does ws come from? Could this be made into a self-contained function please?